# Perl-Threads: share GLOB between threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I try to make a parallel-processing webserver in Perl.

The listening is not a pure socket - so no filehandle, it is a object that implements a HTTP-server (a GLOB).

After the accept I get a GLOB again for the client-connection.

Because of GLOB I can not pass it to the worker-threads vis thead::shared.

I could create the treads dynamically and give it to them via argument. But creating threads is not good for performance so I like to have a fixed pool of already waiting workers.

So how can I pass a GLOB to a already running thread in an elegant way?
Serializing into a DB, File, IPC, ... is not efficient.

Sure I can do a big redesign (fork, IPC, socket, ...) but thats not the question.

Thanks!

Comment: The only reason a glob would have been used as the basis as the object is if was a file handle (even if also an object), and ultimately unpassable even if you were ok with serializing!

Comment: Yes, I was not able to pass or serialize. Think I need to rebuild :-(

Comment: Normally, you'd accept the request in each thread.

Comment: Tell us what this object that represents an http server is?  Does it use cpan code (if so, what), or private stuff (if so, show at least some of it)?

Comment: I am using HTTP::Daemon. Even that is not shareable.

Comment: is this windows?  if not, why are you using threads?

Comment: It is linux. I am with threads because they are more lightweight than fork and sharing data is more easier  -  I thought ;-)

Comment: @chris01 With Perl, threads are not more lightweight. Perl's threads more or less simulate a fork() in userspace, which means they can't share memory via copy-on-write like the real fork() does. Each thread runs its own full copy of the Perl interpreter. Historically, this thread implementation grew out of the fork()-simulation for Windows. The only advantage of Perl threads over fork is that it's typically simpler to share data between threads. You've found a case where sharing is not simple.

Comment: From the [`threads` docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html): “The "interpreter-based threads" provided by Perl are not the fast, lightweight system for multitasking that one might expect or hope for. Threads are implemented in a way that make them easy to misuse. Few people know how to use them correctly or will be able to provide help. The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.”

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to be more specific without some example code.

But the standard way of handing off stuff to workers, is to use `Thread::Queue`.

If it's just a file descriptor, you can `enqueue` it. If it's a bit more complicated (e.g. object or hash), you can use `Storable` and `freeze`/`thaw`. You're probably looking at that because you seem to be talking about an object.

But I wouldn't worry *too* much about your efficiency question - it may not be as big a deal as you think. Are you profiling your code to be sure?

Comment: Thread::Queue is not able to work with GLOB - same limitations than shared_clone. And a serialization seems to be not effizient if the worktask is pretty short.